# How do I calculate spherical coordinates of a point "in" or "on" Earth from the entry point (lat/long), angle/direction of entry and distance/depth?

Tags: spherical-coordinates

All kids at some point ask themselves "if I dig a hole in the Earth and keep digging, where will I end up?". I certainly remember thinking this. I would like to try and work this out. But I have no idea where to start.

So if I wanted to figure out where in the world I'd be (lat/long/depth) if I dug a hole (1km) at an angle of 25 degrees, in the direction of north, from my current GPS coords, how could I calculate this?

A weird question, I know. But it's fascinated me for a while so I thought it was worth asking.

Comment: Depends on precision you want. For example, do you consider Earth to be a sphere? If you dig to north, then longitude doesn't change, so you can start by drawing circle corresponding to current latitude (if you assume Earth to be spherical, it's just a circle with Earth radius), your current point and segment you are going to dig.

Comment: Thanks for your response @mihaild. I am looking for something pretty accurate. I have already been able to calculate the exit point from the Earth, from an angle of entry at any lat/long. This I've tested and it appears to be pretty accurate. I'm not just finding the antipodes here. But I'm really struggling to work out how to arrive at GPS coords (at the nearest point at the surface) if the path is limited by a distance. Essentially I've got everything but the method of calculating the coords inside the Earth if the path isn't considered infinitely long.

Comment: If you want to find the closest to end of tunnel point on surface - isn't it enough that it is on radius that goes through this end?

Comment: I may not have explained myself very well. Sorry. I'm not looking for the GPS coords at the surface. I'm looking for the coords underground. So, let's say I dig a tunnel at an angle of 45 degrees into the Earth in the direction of 273 degrees. The tunnel will have a length of 1 km. Where that 1 km ends, I'd like to be able to calculate the GPS coords at the point where a subsequent hole could be dug, directly down from the surface to meet the end point. I'd like to calculate the lat/lon and depth at the point that the subsequent hole would be dug.